# InDesign GREP: replace final letter of words from a defined list

Tags: replace, grep, find, adobe-indesign

I'm trying to write a broad find/change command for InDesign which looks for words from a defined list (the list is long, around 500 words) and replaces the final character with something else.

Let's say I want words some words ending "-e" to instead end "-i" (so "table" becomes "tabli").

This would be easy to do if I wanted this change to happen on every word ending -e:

find: `e\>`

change: `i`

but what if I only want this change to happen on a particular list of words, like only nouns? The method above would change:

**I see a table**

to:

**I sei a tabli**

when what we want would be:

**I see a tabli**

Short of writing 500 different find/change expressions for each word, is there a way to apply this to only words from a pre-defined list?

Comment: I see two options: (1) use the built-in script `FindChageByList.jsx` (you have to modify the file `FindChangeList.txt`) or (2) write your own script. Perhaps, technically, it can be done with a single GREP expression but it will look awful, it should include all these 500 words within one line... Probably it will excess some limits for an grep expression.

Comment: Yes, I agree a GREP would be extremely unwieldy — my intention is to make it as integrated into a simple InDesign workflow as possible (it will be used by people who aren't familiar with scripts), but it certainly seems as though a script is the easiest way to achieve it with the necessary length of wordlist. I'll try the script you've put below and see if it's feasible, thanks

Comment: Btw, there is the way to add any script as a regular menu command or context menu command.

Comment: So did you try the suggested solution? Could you please provide some feedback?

Comment: Attempting, struggling to get the script installed and running but will report back once I have managed it

Comment: So do you have a problem with 'installing' the script? You can google it, there is nothing complicated at all. Just save a .jsx file into the special folder.

Comment: I deleted my answer since there is no reaction fro the asker. The question looks abandoned.